# Why I'm getting null for a string in F#?

Tags: f#, null

One of the benefits of the type system on F# is avoid a null exception... or that was something I believe... because I'm getting a null problem:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Customer = {
    [<AutoIncrement>] id:option<int64>
    code:string
    name:string
}
```

I'm running a SQL code:

```
let SqlFTS<'T>(table:string, searchTable:string, query:string) =
    use db = openDb()
    let sql = sprintf "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id in (SELECT docid FROM  %s WHERE data MATCH %A)" table searchTable query
    printfn "%A" sql
    db.SqlList<'T>(sql) |> Seq.toArray

testCase "Customers" <| 
    fun _ -> 
        let rows = GenData.genCustomers(50)
        Customers.insert(rows)
        isEqual "Failed to insert" 50L (DB.SqlCount<Customers.Customer>())
        //Until here, it works
        let c = Customers.byId(1L)
        printfn "%A" c
        //Customers.byId return me a record with all the properties as NULLS!
        //Then c.name is null, and the code above fail.
        let rows = Customers.searchCustomers(c.name)
```

This was *very* unexpected. Why I can get a record with all values to null?

Comment: As soon as you interact with "traditional" .NET/CLR things, `null` is just as normal in F# as it is in C#. In particular, strings can always be `null`, and there is no way to make a string non-nullable. The safety from `null` references only covers F#'s own types like records and discriminated unions, not "normal" CLR types.

Comment: So, this is expected behaviour? BTW, this can happen also with Ocalm/haskell?

Comment: If you are asking how/why `Customers.byId` is returning bad data, I would recommend showing us the code of that function.  Generally speaking, strings are nullable in F#. Immutability prevents them from being mutated to null without your knowledge, but you or a black box 3rd party library are indeed allowed to null-initialize them if you want to.

Comment: I'm using NServiceKit under the hood, and its made on C#. so that is the root culprit. Still a unexpected development, because mean the "this can't be null, the type system protect you" is no true (and I must take in account this fact), as I have imagine in my initial learning of F#

Comment: The F# type system does a pretty good job of protecting you from nulls. But when you're using a C# library, that library isn't using the F# type system, is it? I'd rather deal with nulls at the periphery of my F# code than be prevented from calling anything that wasn't written in F#, which is pretty much the only other option.

Comment: It is true as long as you stay within F#'s own type system, but for .NET interoperability, F# must make compromises. That was the only way to allow using a functional language on a fundamentally object-oriented platform like .NET.

Comment: Ok, is clear now. Can add this as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with line 1:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
```

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289724.aspx) for CLIMutable state

> Adding this attribute to a record type causes it to be compiled to a Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) representation with a default constructor with property getters and setters.

That default constructor means the fields will be initialized to default values. The default value for string is null. That's valid to the CLR and it's valid to C# and VB.NET. You may not be able to call the default ctor from F#, but pretty much anyone else can.

Welcome to interop; it can be a pain.